# Javascript in AEMto add a class if a checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, aem

I am trying to target a class called 'horizontal-video' in a div within an AEM component and if the author has clicked a checkbox that has an ID of 'coral-id-540' I want to add a second class called 'flipped' to the div.  Here is the code I wrote that isn't working. Could someone help me figure out why it's not working? The console does not show errors.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("horizontal-video");

$('#coral-id-540').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).addClass("flipped");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("flipped");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible you're not waiting for the DOM to completely load, (or at least have this bit of code below the element in question on the page during page load)

Is your code wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){ //your code });`?

Also, be aware that any element that is dynamically added to the page by JavaScript/jQuery after page load will not have a listener attached using the method you're using.

To allow dynamically added elements to be included in your listener, you should target an ancestor node and add the listener to that node. In plain English: attach the listener to a "higher up" element. The safest (although slowest) node being `document` itself, but it's better to target something closer:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $horizontalVideo = $(".horizontal-video"); //You're using jQuery - why not use it here? Also, I always name jQuery objects with a `$` in front as a shorthand to know it's wrapped in a jQuery object. Plus, a more descriptive name will help you immensely.

    //replace parent-of-coral with the ID of a parent element that you know exists on DOM ready:
    $("#parent-of-coral").on("change", "#coral-id-540", function (e) { //get used to using "e" as the event variable for preventing default / stopping propagation / etc
        $this = $(this); //cache $(this) reference rather than creating another jQuery object each time you use it

        if ($this.is(":checked")) {
            $this.addClass("flipped");
        } else {
            $this.removeClass("flipped");
        }
    });
});
```